# How do I move a Wordpress site and search and replace the database without getting an Internal Server Error?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I moved a Wordpress website to work on it and now I am moving it back.  I followed the exact instructions under this section:
Changing Your Domain Name and URLs
http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

And after uploading the database and the files to the site and re-saving my Permalinks it works but my Nav menu goes back to my development website.

I have moved several Wordpress websites so I tried some search and replace tools, first I tried:
https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

After running this the home page shows up but every other page gives me and Internal Server Error

So I tried a different method I re-uploaded the backed up files and database and this time I used a plug-in with Wordpress:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/

This yields the same result Internal Server Error

What should I do?  (Does anyone know where the nav menu items are in the Wordpress database?  should I just change them?)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your .htaccess is not writeable so when you go to permalinks and save, it doesn't overwrite it with the correct one?
Make sure in the database it is also correct url in the settings in admin if you can access it. If not change it using phpmyadmin. 
I hope that works. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I can get to and change my htaccess file, I know because I put in some redirects.  I can get to General Settings in the Wordpress dashboard and the URLs are correct.  Not sure what table to check in the database.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it was very simple after I used one of the Search and Replace tools I needed to Resave Permalinks again, making sure to do it right: click on a different setting (ex. Default), save permalinks then click back on original (ex. Custom) and resave permalinks again.  (I had saved Permalinks once when I first moved the database and then second time didn't do it the correct way.)